# Probability Question - Independent Events

Tags: probability

> > Let $D_1, D_2, D_3$ be three four-sided dice whose sides have been labeled as follows:
>
> $$D_1 : 0 3 3 3$$
>
> $$D_2 : 2 2 2 5$$
>
> $$D_3 : 1 1 4 6$$
>
> The three dice are rolled at random. Let $A, B, C$ be the events that
>   the outcome on die $D_1$ is larger than the outcome on $D_2$, the
>   outcome on $D_2$ is larger than the outcome on $D_3$, and the outcome
>   on $D_3$ is larger than the outcome on $D_1$, respectively. Show that
>
> (a) $P(A)=\displaystyle\frac{9}{16}$
>
> (b) $P(B)=\displaystyle\frac{9}{16}$
>
> (C) $P(C)=\displaystyle\frac{10}{16}$

I know that if three events are independent, then $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B), P(A\cap C)=P(A)P(C), P(B\cap C)=P(B)P(C)$ and $P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)$.

If someone walks me through how to do one of the parts I will most likely be able to figure out the other two on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If someone walks me through how to do one of the parts I will most likely be able to figure out the other two on my own.

Simply calculate the probabilities for the events as, for example:

$$\begin{split}\mathsf P(B)~&=~\mathsf P(D_2>D_3)\\[1ex] &=~\mathsf P(D_2=2)~\mathsf P(D_3=1)+\mathsf P(D_2=5)~\mathsf P(D_3\in\{1,4\}) \\[1ex] &=~\tfrac 34\cdotp\tfrac 24+\tfrac 14\cdotp\tfrac 34\\[1ex]&=~\tfrac 9{16} \end{split}$$